# vectorize/broadcast nested loops in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'm relatively new to python / numpy.
I was translating some code from c to python, and just found out that python is not really efficient dealing with for loops.
Then I was adding Numba to speed up the process which did the trick for x7 , but read that by working directly in arrays the process could be a lot faster than using the loops.

I've been looking around how to vectorize code, but my lack of knowledge in numpy blocks me.

I would really appreciate some help in finding and understanding a pythonic way to optimize the following array manipulations in nested for loops:

```
import time
import numpy as np

def FindAngle(pa1,pa2,pb1,pb2,roll=0,tilt=0,pan=0):

    # Adjust these for performance/accuracy
    N = 90
    scalefactor = 4 

    panrange, rollrange, tiltrange  = 180, 90, 90
    
    minerror = 1e32
    first = 0

    if first == 0 :
        panrange  = np.deg2rad(panrange)
        rollrange = np.deg2rad(rollrange)
        tiltrange = np.deg2rad(tiltrange)
    else :
        panrange  /= scalefactor
        rollrange /= scalefactor
        tiltrange /= scalefactor

    first += 1 # Number of times called
   
    p3da1 = CalcP(pa1[0],pa1[1])
    p3da2 = CalcP(pa2[0],pa2[1])
    p3db1 = CalcP(pb1[0],pb1[1])
    p3db2 = CalcP(pb2[0],pb2[1])

    for ir in range(-N,+N):

        for it in range(-N,+N):

            for ip in range(-N,+N):

                newroll = roll + rollrange * ir / N
                newtilt = tilt + tiltrange * it / N
                newpan  = pan  + panrange  * ip / N

                p3da1new = RotateZ(p3da1   ,newpan)
                p3da1new = RotateX(p3da1new,newtilt)
                p3da1new = RotateY(p3da1new,newroll)

                p3da2new = RotateZ(p3da2   ,newpan)
                p3da2new = RotateX(p3da2new,newtilt)
                p3da2new = RotateY(p3da2new,newroll)

                p3db1new = RotateZ(p3db1   ,newpan)
                p3db1new = RotateX(p3db1new,newtilt)
                p3db1new = RotateY(p3db1new,newroll)

                p3db2new = RotateZ(p3db2   ,newpan)
                p3db2new = RotateX(p3db2new,newtilt)
                p3db2new = RotateY(p3db2new,newroll)

                phia1 = np.arctan2(p3da1new[0],p3da1new[1])
                phia2 = np.arctan2(p3da2new[0],p3da2new[1])

                phib1 = np.arctan2(p3db1new[0],p3db1new[1])
                phib2 = np.arctan2(p3db2new[0],p3db2new[1])

                error = np.fabs(phia2 - phia1) + np.fabs(phib2 - phib1)
                
                if error < minerror :
                    bestpan  = newpan
                    besttilt = newtilt
                    bestroll = newroll
                    minerror = error

    return np.array([bestpan, besttilt, bestroll])

def CalcP(longitude,latitude):
    longitude = np.deg2rad(longitude)
    latitude = np.deg2rad(latitude)
    px = np.cos(latitude) * np.sin(longitude)
    py = np.cos(latitude) * np.cos(longitude)
    pz = np.sin(latitude)
    return np.array([px, py, pz])

def RotateX(p,theta):
    x =  p[0]
    y =  p[1] * np.cos(theta) + p[2] * np.sin(theta)
    z = -p[1] * np.sin(theta) + p[2] * np.cos(theta)
    return np.array([x, y, z])

def RotateY(p,theta):
    x = p[0] * np.cos(theta) - p[2] * np.sin(theta)
    y = p[1]
    z = p[0] * np.sin(theta) + p[2] * np.cos(theta)
    return np.array([x, y, z])

def RotateZ(p,theta):
    x =  p[0] * np.cos(theta) + p[1] * np.sin(theta)
    y = -p[0] * np.sin(theta) + p[1] * np.cos(theta)
    z =  p[2]
    return np.array([x, y, z])

pa1 = [92.79092408765709,-35.660113846604126]
pa2 = [121.09811757262577,12.300475314449452]
pb1 = [-169.27464527267904,-70.06597683481246]
pb2 = [-176.08193221857982,5.115846609482374]

start_time = time.time()
angles0 = FindAngle(pa1,pa2,pb1,pb2)
print("%g, %g, %g\n" %(angles0[0],angles0[1],angles0[2]))
print("TOTAL --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: https://realpython.com/numpy-array-programming/

Comment: This a very very general question and no one wants to do the work for you. So please have a look at the abundance of resources found online.

Comment: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-for-data/9781449323592/ch04.html

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: Full code translation and/or explanation of `numpy` is too broad a question for SO, but I have to ask - what exactly is that code even supposed to be doing?

Comment: Oh wait, I think I get it, it's a spherical procrutes analysis.  You don't need to solve that iteratively, but you'll probably want to ask a math stack how to do it first and then try to implement.  If you have specific problems to implement in `numpy`, we'll be here.

Comment: I even found the algorithm : [Kabsch algorthim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm)

Comment: If you need just need results: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.align_vectors.html You can get a rotation matrix from the result https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.html#scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation

Comment: T @DanielF yes it's for vertically align some 3d lines in a spherical environment. Thanks for pointing to the Kabsch algorthim it actualkly does something pretty similar, but unfortunatelly it's not the same approach as the one I need to achieve. Actually on the math parts it's fine, even it's using brute force to test all combinations. The implemenation in c it just work fine and perform really fast, the problem are those 3 nested loops in python which makes the whole code run for 70s ( 10 with numba) .

Comment: @Joe I have already been playing around with align_vectors, the issue here is that is moving both set of vectors so they can just fit. My goal is to have a blocked set of vectors, and find the rotation matrix or euler angles to fit the first set of vectors into the blocked one.

Comment: I don't think that they are moving both sets, that would not make sense at all. It returns `Best estimate of the rotation that transforms b to a.`, so `a` is fixed. For the other way, that is maybe done be inverting the matrix.